# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I created a user in [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) with this command:

```
createuser --interactive
```

But it didn't ask for a new password, so I figured that the password is set to the sudo password of my computer. However, when I tried to connect to my database, using this code:

```
async function connect() {
    let connection_string = "postgres://[username]:[password]@localhost:5432/[database]"
    let client = new pg.Client(connection_string)
    await client.connect()

    let query = await client.query("select * from Messages;")
    query.rows.forEach(row => {
        console.log(row)
    })
    await client.end()
}
```

I received this error:

```
(node:7106) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "[username]"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone who gets here, if the parameter passed to ```new pg.Client()``` (ie ```connection_string``` in the above variable) is a bad URL, then you will get the same error regardless. For example ```new pg.Client(undefined)``` will also give the error ```error: password authentication failed for user <username>```. Seems like it would be a good idea to give a more useful error message as this was pretty misleading for me.

Comment: If you're using ```node.js``` ```dotenv``` and ```pg``` make sure you have ```require('dotenv').config();``` in your ```index.js```. This fixed this error once I added it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying access methods on the pg_hba.conf to trust, did it for me.

```sh
$ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf
```

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

reload the service, and try to connect again.

```
const DB_URI = "postgresql:///<database_here>";
let db = new Client({ connectionString: DB_URI });
db.connect();
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Zorin OS 16

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me:**

login to a priviledge user in psql

e.g. `sudo -u postgres psql`

create a new user:

```
CREATE USER new_user WITH PASSWORD 'password123';
```

change ownership of database:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname OWNER TO new_owner;
```

change ownership of table:

```
ALTER TABLE public.table_name OWNER TO new_owner;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the user,

```
drop owned by [username];
drop user [username];
```

and re-created the user, this time instead with this command:

```
createuser -P -s -e [username]
```

Now, it asks for a new password to be given to this user. And then the same code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    async function connect() {
        let connection_string = "postgres://[username]:[password]@localhost:5432/[database]"
        let client = null;
        try {
         new pg.Client(connection_string)
         } catch (e) {
          console.log (e);
return;
         }
try {
        await client.connect()
} catch (e) {
return;
}

try {
        let query = await client.query("select * from Messages;")
} catch(e) {
return ;
}
        query.rows.forEach(row => {
            console.log(row)
        })
        await client.end()
    }
```

You can handle the error by using try catch block.
Now for why the error is coming, whatever username/password you are providing its wrong as its failing to connect with this details

Answer (score 0):

I don't aware about **Postgres DB**, But I suggest one thing you need to do when working with NodeJS. NodeJS provides a **unhandledRejection** hook to handle every promise rejection globally. You can use it by adding such peace of code in your main file (**server.js or app.js**).

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  // call a function which will send a mail of this rejection
});
```

You can get a better understanding by monitoring **reason & promise**.
I hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below simple code for connecting with the PostgreSQL Database. 
Create a new user with credentials like username: education and password: password007 .

```
 var express = require('express'),
    pg = require('pg'),
    app = express();

//DB Connect String
var connect = "postgres://education:password007@localhost/recipebookdb";


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //Pg Connect
    // var pool = new pg.Pool()
    // console.log(req.params.user_id);
    pg.connect(connect, function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error facing client from pool', err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', function (err, result) {
            if(err) {
                return console.error('error runnign query', err);
            }
            res.render('index', {recipes: result.rows});
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the error by using try catch also you need to log the reason for the unhandledRejection. here is an example as per your scenario

```
async function connect() {
    try {
        let connection_string = "postgres://[username]:[password]@localhost:5432/[database]"
        let client = new pg.Client(connection_string)
        await client.connect()
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    try {
        let query = await client.query("select * from Messages;");

        query.rows.forEach(row => {
            console.log(row)
        })

        await client.end()
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', reason.stack || reason)
  });
```